# Calculate in which Voronoi cell a coordinate pair lies

Tags: mesh, delaunaymesh

Suppose I have a Voronoi diagram labeled like this:

```
coords = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
ptsLabels = Text[#, coords[[#]], {0, 0}] & /@ Range[Length@coords];
vm = VoronoiMesh[coords];
Graphics[{Thin, Black, MeshPrimitives[vm, 1], {Red, ptsLabels}}]
```

[image]

Given a coordinate pair $(x,y)$, how can I calculate in which of the 10 cells it lies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Voronoi diagram cells represent regions with the same nearest point, so you can easily do this with `Nearest[coords->"Index"]` to get the index of the nearest point.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
coords = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
ptsLabels = Text[#, coords[[#]], {0, 0}] & /@ Range[Length@coords];
vm = VoronoiMesh[coords];
nf = Nearest[coords -> "Index"];
(* Now we can do nf[{x,y}] to find the cell index containing this point {x,y} *)
 
DynamicModule[{p = {0.5, 0.5}},
 {Graphics[{Thin, Black, MeshPrimitives[vm, 1], {Red, ptsLabels}, 
    Locator[Dynamic[p]]}], Dynamic[nf[p]]}
 ]
```

If you drag around the locator in the Voronoi diagram, you'll see the number on the right should be the cell that the locator is currently in.

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[2];
coords = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {6, 2}]; (* for testing *)

vm = VoronoiMesh[coords, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
  , MeshCellLabel -> {2 -> "Index"}
  , Epilog -> {
    Red, Point@pts
    , Blue, Point@coords
    }
  ]

Transpose[{pts, Last@First@NearestMeshCells[vm, #] & /@ pts}]
```

> {{{0.664971, 0.843882}, 6}, {{0.56904, 0.398212},    9}, {{0.238652,
> 0.673513}, 5}, {{0.419507, 0.587398},    4}, {{0.00833523, 0.942441}, 5}, {{0.771263, 0.147503}, 8}}

To get the polygon for the 6th cell (e.g.):

```
MeshPrimitives[vm, 2][[6]]
```

---

*Visualization:*

[image]